# How to Create Multiple Documents in Firestore With Custom ID for each Document in Python

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i have around 700k records and want to upload them to firestore.
is there any way to create multiple documents in a collection with custom id for each document?

Comment: Does this documentation on "batched writes" help?  
 Also see the section marked ★ on bulk data entry  https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes

Comment: There's also this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58897274/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-write-a-lot-of-documents-to-firestore

Comment: thanks db.batch() worked for me