# Insert multiple records into Firebase with loop?

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

Hey i am make a schedule component in Angular and where i have a form that the user fills out ->

Model:_____
StartDate: _____
QTY: ______

Now, I would like it to be stores in that each one is its own record: For example, if i put quantity as 5, it will have 5 records (this way i can make each unit complete). What I have so far is below:

```
for (let counter = 1; counter < Qty + 1; Counter++)
    {
        db.collection("sched").add({
        Model: "FakeModel",
        StartDate: "06-06-2020",
        UnitNumber: counter,
        complete: false
    });
}
```

There seems like there should be a better way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use a batch. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes

Comment: How are you thinking this would be easier?  Adding N documents requires creating N document references for use with `add()` or `set()`.  There is no shortcut here.  You can use a batch, but you still have to create N references with data to add to the batch.  There are no "bulk create" options.

Comment: I'm not thinking it would be easier, as that is relatively easy, just seemed like a 'scabby' way to do it.

Comment: Unless you can be specific about what is scabby about it, it'll be hard to help. To me this looks like a normal way to create documents, and I don't think a batch is pertinently better (also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58897274/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-write-a-lot-of-documents-to-firestore).