# Fast Way of Writing Data to Firestore from BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-dataflow

I have requirement to load about 10 million data from BigQuery to firestore every day. Which is the fastest way to do this ?

Cloud function with parallel individual writes is an option (according to the below link), but in this case, parallelizing the bigquery table would be challenge.

[What is the fastest way to write a lot of documents to Firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58897274/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-write-a-lot-of-documents-to-firestore)

Does Dataflow works in this scenario, read and write data through Dataflow ?

Answer (score 1):

Dataflow works in this case. It lets you parallelize how you read data from BigQuery and write it into Firestore.

There is a work-in-progress to add a Firestore sink to Beam. It should be available for the Java SDK in Beam 2.31.0: See https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/14261

In the meantime, you may be able to roll your own: In Python it would be like so:

```py
(p 
 | ReadFromBigQuery(...)
 | GroupIntoBatches(50)  # Batches of 50-500 elements will help with throughput
 | ParDo(WriteToFirestoreDoFn())
```

Where you write your own `WriteToFirestoreDoFn` that does something like this:

```py
class WriteToFirestoreDoFn(DoFn):
  def __init__(self, firestore_info):
    self.client = None
    self.firestore_info = firestore_info
  
  def process(self, batch):
    if not self.client:
      self.client = firestore.Client(self.firestore_info)
    self.client.write_data(batch)
```

This is a little pseudocody, but it should help you get started with what you want.

Comment: Great, any performance numbers to share now ? And what could be best batch size ? According to firestore doc, max 10k writes can be done against the database per second

Comment: I am not sure, as I don't know firestore well. I have used 500 record inserts before, but it may vary. I recommend you test it out. I suppose that 150 records may be reasonable, and allow you to reach high parallelism for your transform