# Cloud Firestore - Parallel Individual Writes vs Parallel Batch Writes

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-dataflow

Does anyone have compared the performance between doing Parallel Individual Writes vs Parallel Batch Writes against Firestore ?

I am trying to write data to Firestore everyday using a Dataflow import job and able to write around 2.5 million records in 10 mins. Currently the write is done in batch mode with a batch size of 400.

Just curious if individual writes can give more performance than batch writes ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58897274/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-write-a-lot-of-documents-to-firestore) that pretty much compares and explain the differences between Parallel Individual Writes vs Parallel Batch Writes with Firestore.