# Add large array of objects in firestore collection

Tags: arrays, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, collections

I tried to add a large array of objects in firebase collection but it is taking too much time. The array has around 60 000 rows and I need to provide every single object. To do this I need to loop thru all array elements:

```html
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++ {
  this.someFunName(array[i])
}
```

The firebase function is:

```html
  someFunName(element) {
    return this._firestore
    .collection('collName').add(element);
  }
```

For around 5 min only 1500 elements where recorded.
Do you have any suggestions how to handle it or some alternative?
I know that the array is too large.

Regards

Comment: Do you need to create a new document for each element in your array?

Comment: Yes, this is the function. In this way a separated document with id is created in the collection.

Comment: Is it a one time operation? E.g. an initialization of the database.

Comment: No it is not a one time operation and from here the issue comes because time to time a such file will be needed to be uploaded and this will take huge amount of time.

Comment: I think you should either use ‘map’ or ‘forEach’ to reduce the time instead of ‘for’ loop. For reference you can go through these documents: [1] https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/map [2] https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach

Comment: Regarding map and forEach you are definitely right, they are faster but the problem is not to loop thru the array, the problem is these 60 k request to firebase. Firebase has some limits and I'm searching a proper way to write this large information faster.

For example if I load these 60k rows from a csv file with forEach the file is rendered for 10-15 seconds but the requests to firebase for these 60k rows will took around 40 min (around 1500 records for 5 min).

Comment: Sorry, they are 40 requests (not 40 min) x 5 min each = 200 min (over 3hours). That is the reason to search more optimal way to do it.

Comment: According to this documentation[1], you can use the server client library for bulk writes. And you can refer to this stackoverflow answer[2] in which a Firebase engineer has explained in detail about the time taken to write while using the server client library. I think this should help you.
[1] https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes
[2] https://stackoverflow.com/a/58897275/15774177