# Write data to Firestore Concurrently in Bulk

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a use case where I need to generate a pre-calculated document and save it to a firestore collection.

The approach is to create a `tasks` collection, and each document is `tasks` will be used to trigger the `onCreate` event in cloud functions.

Each `onCreate` event will take ~40s to finish then write to a `samples` collection.

The number of tasks is 244 * 26 = 6344 documents that need to be written the `samples` collection.

Here are the steps that clouds function triggers.

**Step 1**: Create 244 documents in `tasks` (run every 1 hour)

**Step 2**: `onCreate` will listen to the event -> generate documents which takes ~40s each. It means we have 244 functions concurrently running and writing 26 documents document to `samples` collection.

The function that I use to write data

```
export const generateData = async () => {
  const promises = []
  for (const sample of samples) {
    // some logics
    promises.push(sampleRef.set(sampleData))
  }
  await Promise.all(promises)
  return
}
```

This is the error that I got:

```
Error: 4 DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: Deadline exceeded
    at Object.callErrorFromStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:31:26)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:179:52)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:336:141)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:299:181)
    at /workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:145:78
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11)
```

Any thoughts on what happened or are there other ways to do it? Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be quite a few reasons for this error :

1. It can be related to @grpc/grpc-js as the error suggests. A lot of
   @google-cloud libraries with a @grpc/grpc-js dependency have an open
   issue related to concurrency. The only thing I've read that helps
   people seems to be  :

   ```
      Upgrading your Node version to v13( assuming you are using node as the runtime).
   ```

   See [this](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/issues/1158) for more details.
2. This may be an issue for dispatching multiple tasks concurrently.
   Temporary solution is : Submit tasks sequentially. One by one.
   Possible workarounds :

- Setting the flag fallback : true while creating tasks has resolved
  the issue for some.

  ```
   const {CloudTasksClient} = require('@google-cloud/tasks');
   const client = new CloudTasksClient({ fallback: true })
  ```

  Setting fallback to true enables a different transport (the one that was
  initially supposed for browsers) - instead of using [gRPC](https://grpc.io/), it
  serializes your requests and sends them over regular HTTP/1 connection
  with node-fetch to a different endpoint. When you enable fallback, you
  don't do any gRPC requests at all - it uses a totally different stack.
  If you are scheduling many tasks concurrently and if you perform
  Promise.all with a large number of tasks, you can run into contention on
  resources, which can lead to issues like DEADLINE_EXCEEDED.
- If you have many tasks to enqueue in on job, an approach I take is as follows :

  ```
    const tasksToCreate = [...]; // an array with a large number of tasks to enqueue.
    const WORK_SIZE = 32; // some size of work to perform.
    while (work.length > 0) {
    const work = tasksToCreate.slice(0, WORK_SIZE).map(() => {
    return createTaskPromise();
    });
    await Promise.all(work);

    }
  ```

3. Keeping in mind that Firestore has limits, probably “Deadline Exceeded”
   may also happen because of its limits. [Maximum write rate](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-cloud-firestore-discuss/tGaZpTWQ7tQ/NdaDGRAzBgAJ)  to a document is 1 per second. See [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas). People performing too many writes too quickly can go through this issue. For now when you hit this, probably retrying the write and perhaps slowing down the rate at which writes are performed may help.

   Have a look [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/client/libraries#server_client_libraries) at all the other possible causes of this error

**Solution :**

There are three common ways to perform a large number of write operations on Firestore.

- Perform each individual write operation in sequence.
- Using batched write operations.
- Performing individual write operations in parallel.

The fastest and most efficient way to perform bulk data writes on Firestore is by performing parallel individual write operations. For bulk data entry, use a [server client library](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/client/libraries#server_client_libraries) with parallelized individual writes. You should use a server client library for bulk data operations and not a mobile/web SDK.

Batched writes perform better than serialized writes but not better than parallel writes. Batched writes create a BatchedWrite object by calling batch(), until it has a maximum capacity of 500 documents, and then write it to Firestore. The solution counts every operation which is made to the batch and after the limit is reached a new batch is created and pushed to the batchArray.
After all updates are completed the code loops through the batchArray and commits every batch which is inside the array.
It is important to count every operation set(), update(), delete() which is made to the batch because they all count to the 500 operation limit.

Have a look at this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58897275/15803365) thread for the detailed analysis on the three write operations.

Comment: Thank @Priyashree for your detailed answer. I ended up running each individual write operation in sequence. 

Some more information: 

- Current Node version: 14x
- Running batch still has the same issue.