# How to add a new field in all the firebase documents?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a firebase application on the App Store. In the users collection in firebase, I have a bunch of fields like first_name, last_name, etc. I want to add another field (age) in all the existing documents. How can I do that? If I don't update it, the application gives errors saying that the field doesn't exist in the document.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing special about this:

1. Read all documents.
2. Loop over the results.
3. Update each of them.

Since you tagged with Cloud Functions, in Node.js this would be something like:

```
const usersRef = db.collection('users');
const snapshot = await usersRef.get();
await Promise.all(snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.ref.update({age: 42})));
```

This is based on these links from the Firebase documentation:

- [getting all documents in a collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection)
- [updating a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data)

You might also want to look at:

- [What is the fastest way to write a lot of documents to Firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58897274/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-write-a-lot-of-documents-to-firestore)