# How to update all collection in firebase firestore in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have two collections. One collection "User", who contains the user info (name...) And one collection "Post" who contains all posts of my flutter application. A post document contains many fields like a "Title", "Name" of the user. I add an option in my application to allow the user to change his name. But I must change the name in the "User" collection and in all posts it creates in the "Post" collection. How should I do it? Can anyone help me with an example?

Comment: You can iterate Updating name from `User` collection is very simple you must have known about it. To update the name of user in `Post` collection you can query like this 
`FirebaseFirestore.collection("Post").where("name", isEqualTo: pass the previous/non updated name here)`.get and then iterate over the documents you get containing the name of the user.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing magical here. You'll need to [get all post documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection) for that user with a [query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries), and then [update them](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data) one by one or in [batches](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes).

I'd also recommend checking out: [What is the fastest way to write a lot of documents to Firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58897274/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-write-a-lot-of-documents-to-firestore)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on which firestore are you using.

For Cloud Firestore:

You can update like this way, this is the case where you are updating just one field of your user.

```
final docRef = db.collection("users").doc("user_id");
final updates = <String, dynamic>{
  "timestamp": FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
};

docRef.update(updates).then(
    (value) => print("DocumentSnapshot successfully updated!"),
    onError: (e) => print("Error updating document $e"));
```

For updating a nested field:

```
// Assume the document contains:
// {
//   Title: "Post Tittle",
//   Name: "Post Name"
//   user: { id: "1", name: "User Name" }
//   date: "2022-12-08"
// }
db
    .collection("posts")
    .doc("post_id")
    .update({"date": "2022-13-08", "user.name": "New name"});
```

You can see more details here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is a user id attached to each post, you can query from the posts collection where the user (that is changing his/her name) id matches the id that is in the post (from the posts collection) and then modify the user property/attribute from the results.

A sample code would look like this,

**To modify from the user collection**

```
final docRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('users')
    .doc(id);

final response = await docRef
    .update(updatedDateInJson)
    .then((value) => value)
    .onError((error, stackTrace) => error);
```

**To modify from the posts collection where the user is found in a post**

```
final response = FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('posts')
          .where('name', isEqualTo: 'John')
          .get()
          .then((value) async {
              // modify each doc
          });
```

Quick Note: use a onError block to check for errors in updating docs.

Comment: can you please give me an example to modify each doc