# How do I add multiple documents in firebase 9 with javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Their documentation only shows how to set multiple documents with batch, but I need to add new docs and doing it one by one with a loop seems like a bad solution

```
const addHistroy = async (items: IHistory[]) => {
    await items.forEach((item) => {
      addDoc(historyCollectionRef, item);
    });
  };
```

Comment: Can you share your code that you've tried already or what you have right now so we can get some more context on what you are trying to do?

Comment: this is what I wrote in order to add a few, I used a loop, but I'm sure there's a better way to do it:const addHistroy = async (items: IHistory[]) => {
    await items.map((item) => {
      addDoc(historyCollectionRef, item);
    });
  };

Comment: "doing it one by one with a loop seems like a bad solution" If your concern is performance, have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58897274/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-write-a-lot-of-documents-to-firestore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *add* a document using [Batched Writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes) by creating a `DocumentReference` first as shown below:

```
const batch = writeBatch(db);

await items.forEach((item) => {
  // Creates a DocRef with random ID
  const docRef = doc(collection(db, "history_collection_name"));

  batch.set(docRef, item)
});

await batch.commit();
```

If you don't want to use Batched Writes and use a loop (which you might have to if you want to add more than 500 documents at once). Try the following:

The `map()` does not return a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) but `addDoc()` does. So you must `await` the `addDoc()` instead. You cannot use `async-await` with a `forEach` loop so you can either use `for-of` loop or use `Promise.all()` as shown below:

```
const addHistroy = async (items: IHistory[]) => {
  // or alternatively create multiple batched writes of 500
  const promises = items.map((item) => addDoc(historyCollectionRef, item))
  await Promise.all(promises);
  
  console.log("Documents added!")
};
```