# Safe way to delete a child field from all records in Firebase Real Time Database

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-realtime-database

I'm relatively new to firebase and need to delete a certain field from all records in Firestore. This is how the database record structure looks like

```
-> Profiles
  -> UUID ( md5 )
   -> consents ( This needs to be deleted for all profiles )
```

But not all of the profiles have these, and it's a huge database with around 150k records.
I didn't do Firebase Functions so am not sure how to do this safely thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please edit your question to only have the tag for the database you actually use, not with both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no operation to do a bulk update documents in Firestore and add a field to them, so you will have to update each document in turn.

So in a step-by-step process:

1. Read a batch of documents from the database with a [limit](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data) [query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries).
2. Loop over the documents in the result.
3. Add the new field to each of them.
4. Get the next back of documents by [starting after](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors) the last one of the previous batch.

You might also want to read:

- The documentation on [paginating through a large collection with cursors](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors)
- [What is the fastest way to write a lot of documents to Firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58897274/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-write-a-lot-of-documents-to-firestore)